# Require in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can someone explain how would this look in TypeScript. Can it be done via imports?

**JS:**

```
var casper = require('casper').create({})
```

**CoffeeScript:**

```
casper = require("casper").create()
```

> **Visual Studio error:** Error    1   The name ''casper'' does not exist in the current scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together a blog on using require.js with Typescript.
http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/typescript-organizing-your-code-with-amd-modules-and-require-js/
You will be able to write code like this:

```
require["casper", (casper) => {
    var item = casper.create();
};
```

Comment: There are ways to do this WITHOUT introducing the clunky syntax above - check out my answer below to see how.

Answer (score 8):

```
import something = module('something');
var somevar = something.create({});
```

The point to note here I think is that TS today doesn't allow dotting off of module('something') so you have to break your statement into two.

Comment: However, a crucial piece is that you now have to 'declare module something' too, otherwise it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a module flag when you compile your TypeScript:

```
--module commonjs
```

Or

```
--module amd
```

It will convert imports into the appropriate module loading statement:

```
import something = module('something');
var somevar = something.create();
```

Comment: It should work with that. If all else fails you can use your line of JS (you may need to 'declare function requires(name:string):any;'

Answer (score 0):

If that casper thing is something written in JavaScript, you need to declare a module for it too (or else it won't compile).

By convention, you put such declaration in a separate file named casper.d.ts:

```
declare module casper {
    export class SomeClassInCasper {
    }

    export function someFunctionInCasper();
}
```

And you would include a reference to that casper.d.ts at the top above your import/module:

```
/// <reference path="casper.d.js" />

import casper = import("casper");
```

Answer (score 0):

casper is installed through npm on the global scope.

1. typings install dt~casperjs --global --save
2. declare var casper; (on your code)

A short casper with typescript how to can be seen here:

https://medium.com/@guyavraham/smoke-tests-casper-js-with-typescript-8b01b504f3a4

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a fairly comprehensive post on using Require in TypeScript.  My approach does NOT require you to use the ugly

```
require(['dependency'], function() {

}
```

syntax.  Instead, in TypeScript you get to use the convenient `import x = module("x")` syntax.

Comment: "Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0". Please post the content here, as SO is less likely to go offline.